# Limit to how deep a Many-To-Many will go with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

Is there a limit to how deep a select all will go for a many-to-may relationship?  I have a design like this:

Table Survey has many Table Survey Sections.  Table Survey Sections have many Questions.  Table Questions have many Table Possible Responses.

If I do this for the Survey Table:

```
$this->loadModel('Survey');
$this->Survey->recursive = 2;
$getSurvey = $this->Survey->find('all');
```

It will only go as far as the Questions table but bring back the Possible Responses Table.  But, if I query the Survey Sections table, it brings everything back.  Is this an issue with my code or a limit to how deep a search will go?

Here is my Models:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');    
class Survey extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(    
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(    
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'surveySection' => array(
            'className' => 'SurveySection',
            'foreignKey' => 'surveys_id',         
        ),
    );

}

<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');  
class SurveySection extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(

    );
    public $belongsTo = array(

    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Question' => array(
            'className' => 'Question',
            'foreignKey' => 'survey_section_id',
        ),

    );    
}

<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');    
class Question extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(

    );
    public $belongsTo = array(

    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'PossibleResponse' => array(
            'className' => 'PossibleResponse',
            'foreignKey' => 'questions_id',
        ),

    );    
}


<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');   
class PossibleResponse extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(

    );
    public $belongsTo = array(

    );
}
```

Comment: What does your code do when you try `$this->Survey->recursive = 3;` instead of 2?

Comment: I was under the impression the values only went to 2: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive but you are right, changing it to 3 worked.

Comment: I'm not really sure myself it's why I didn't post it as an answer (did it work?). I think the CakePHP book only show an example for a specific case.

Comment: Yeah, it worked.  Post it as a response and Ill approve it.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$this->Survey->recursive = 3;`.

As I said in the comment, the example at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive is a bit misleading because it only show an example for a specific case. In fact you can go as far as you want when fetching data.